# iKVM: return to graphic mode

Tags: linux, remote-control

In iKVM (Supermicro) I have switched to text console mode using `<Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F1>`. How I can switch again to graphic mode? (the same keyshortcut pressing again doesn't do anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tired `<Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F6>`, by default F6 is for graphic mode and first five are for text console in linux from F1 to F5.

Switching back to X Window: `Alt + F7`.

Comment: this is also text mode

Comment: please try to execute `startx` at terminal prompt next time this terminal will use as a graphical mode.

Comment: i think your default runlevel is runlevel `3`.
if u want to switch default runlevel to graphic mode u can edit the file `/etc/inittab`, search for the following word/phrase in `/etc/inittab`

`id:3:initdefault:`

to

`id:5:initdefault:`

Comment: Switching back to X Window: `Alt + F7`

Comment: cool but this shows me empty screen with purple background

Comment: Have you tried to setting parameters from `/etc/inittab`?